# How to use universal link from telegram?

Tags: ios, deeplink

I created universal link for my ios app. and i shared it to telegram as a link but when i clicked on that link it not redirect to open my app that already install in iphone?
How to config it?

Comment: it only open telegram web browser

Comment: Did you find out a solution? The same happens to me